# save a selected custom TableViewCell in CoreData

Tags: core-data

i've got a custom tableViewCell with fetched data and a basket button, how can i save them to another entity(Basket Entity)  with a click to the basket in the cell?

```
- (IBAction)basketButton:(id)sender 
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext]; 
UIButton *button = sender;
NSInteger rowInIndexPath =button.tag;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowInIndexPath inSection:0];
Basket *basket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Basket"        inManagedObjectContext:context];


//missing code

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"fail : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}
```

[Screenshot of my app](http://i40.tinypic.com/191187.jpg)

my Solutions:

i forgot to tell my function the position of the Cell.

```
 - (IBAction)basketButton:(id)sender {
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext]; 
 UIButton *button = sender;
 NSInteger rowInIndexPath =button.tag;
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowInIndexPath inSection:0];
 Basket *basket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Basket" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Product *product = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

basket.productname  =product.productname ;


NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"fail : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}
```

Comment: I have to agree with Palimondo in that I'm not sure exactly what it is you want to save, and to where. I think there is a language barrier at work here. Can you clarify by perhaps telling us about your data model, and your data?

Comment: @ErayGeveci Then please post your own answer, maybe it will be useful to someone in the future. Remember, this site is a community effort.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, where to start... what you ask here does not make any sense. You seem to be unfamiliar with fundamental concepts like model, view, controller, actions... There is no way to answer/solve your problem as it stands.

Try [learning more](http://www.importahmedeid.com/2011/10/02/big-idea-introduction-to-model-view-controller-system-for-ios-applications/) about them. See answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971/can-anyone-recommend-a-complete-objc-cocoa-or-cocoa-touch-tutorial for plenty of resources to get you started.

Comment: Why this doesn't make sense ? please look at my picture below http://i40.tinypic.com/191187.jpg